# Comment s'est répandu le mot « wankage »?

Tags: étymologie, néologismes, afrique

Le mot « wankage » est un néologisme africain récent. Il fait référence au coup d'état de [Daouda Malam Wanké](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daouda_Malam_Wank%C3%A9) en 1999 au Niger. Si j'ai bien compris, il signifie un coup d'état par un militaire qui a promis de démocratiser le pays. (Merci de me rectifier si j'ai mal inféré le sens. D'ailleurs, est-ce que le mot implique que la promesse a été tenue ?)

J'aimerais en savoir plus sur l'historique de ce mot. De quand date-t-il au juste ? Comment s'est-il répandu ? Qui le connaît¹ ?

¹ 
<sub>Pas grand-monde en dehors de l'Afrique francophone j'imagine. Pour ma part, en France, je pense que le seul endroit où je l'ai rencontré est dans des émissions d'actualités africaines sur RFI (où il était employé sans explication), et dans des publications d'Afrique de l'ouest francophone.</sub>

*Note: I know what the word means in English. Please refrain from childish puns or remarks involving the meaning of the English word.*

Comment: Inconnu au bataillon. Et peu de traces chez [saint Google](http://www.google.fr/search?q=wankage&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=LLt&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aunofficial&num=10&lr=lang_fr&ft=i&cr=&safe=off&tbs=).

Comment: Jamais lu ni entendu en Belgique.

Comment: @evpok: le (comparativement) faible taux de pénétration d'internet en Afrique (particulièrement francophone) rend la mesure Google un peu moins révélatrice que d'habitude... (cela dit: jamais entendu en Europe ou même en Outre-Mer français)

Comment: Jamais entendu non plus. Et vu la signification de _"to wank"_ en anglais, je doute que ça perce.

Comment: Je trouve ça particulièrement drôle que la question sous-entend que le mot "wankage" est répandu alors que si peu de gens ne le connaissent...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jamais entendu ni lu sur la presse africaine francophone.
De ce que tu dis sur sa construction (coup d'État de 1999 au Niger), j'aurais tendance à dire que comme bien souvent quand il y a un événement qui marque par son originalité, ou qui marque seulement, on construit un mot à partir de l'événement en question. Sois à partir du nom de la personne, soit à partir du lieu, soit à partir d'un terme qui a marqué dans le discours/ autour de l'événement en question. 
Donc wankage  pour désigner un coup d'État sur le modèle de ce qu'a fait Wanké, ça me parait logique.  D'autres ont fait ça avant (Amadou Toumani Touré [ATT] au Mali en 1991.. mais on garde la mémoire du plus récent bien souvent. D'autres l'ont promis et pas fait (Général Gueï en Côte d'ivoire en 1999, organise les élections, mais ne veut pas avoir perdu...).

La construction est classique aussi "Wankage" sur le modèle d'arbitrage pour arbitre.
Son histoire ? Probablement sorti au moment des élections de décembre 1999, quand on a vu qu'il faisait ce qu'il avait annoncé.

Je cherche une idée d'exemple de construction de mot sur le même modèle (français d'Afrique de l'ouest), mais bien sur, je ne trouve pas. Si ça me revient, je reposte.

Comment: Ça y est, un exemple me revient : déflaté.. (= licencié car déflation. En particulier certains agents de l'État)